# Inheritance from an AbstractUser based Model in django 2.7

Tags: django, python-3.x, inheritance, django-models, abstractuser

I have a Custom User Model extending the AbstractUser and it works fine. But now i want to create another Model that is extending my Custom User Model like this in models.py:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, unique=True)
    town = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False)


class DeleveryPerson(CustomUser):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, unique=True)
```

The problem is that the table DeleveryPerson is created with just the field "code" 
when I expected it to also have fields coming from the CustomUser model. 
So how can i achieve that kind of inheretane between CustomUser and DeleveryPerson. Thk!

Comment: That's how inheritance in Django works - see the docs on [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance). Django automatically creates a one-to-one field between `DeliveryPerson` and the `CustomUser` model. It might be better to do `class DeliveryPerson(models.Model):`, then add your own `one-to-one` field.

Comment: Note you've got a typo - change Del*e*very to Del*i*very

Comment: @Alasdair thank for the reply. I will use the automatically created one-to-one field